# Creating random stream in java and stop at event

Tags: java, stream, iterator

Update the code:
This is a java code .. it should create stream of random observations, each observation contains 4 cloumns, each one is an integer from 0 to 999 ... The code should keep generationg the values and append the observation values to a text file until i press the "s" from the keyboard ..  note that the created observations should only be kept temporarily, and each observation will be deleted after it wrote at the consol and append on the file ..
Question: How to modify the code to create a stream of continous observations  stopped when I press "s"

Here is the code

```
    import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomStreamMatrix {
    private static final int MATRIX_SIZE = 4;
    private static final int MAX_VALUE = 999;
    private static final long SEED = 1234L; // Seed value for random number generation

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomStreamMatrix generator = new RandomStreamMatrix();
        Iterator<int[]> iterator = generator.new RandomMatrixIterator();

        // Create a file to write the observations
        String filePath = "observations.txt";
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath);
            AtomicBoolean generateObservations = new AtomicBoolean(true);

            // Create a separate thread for user input
            Thread userInputThread = new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println("Press 's' to stop the generation...");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                while (generateObservations.get()) {
                    String input = scanner.nextLine();
                    if (input.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                        generateObservations.set(false);
                        System.out.println("Generation stopped by user.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                scanner.close();
            });
            userInputThread.start();

            while (generateObservations.get()) {
                int[] observation = iterator.next();
                System.out.println("Observation: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(observation));

                // Write the observation to the file
                for (int value : observation) {
                    fileWriter.write(Integer.toString(value) + " ");
                }
                fileWriter.write("\n");
                fileWriter.flush();
            }
            fileWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Observations written to " + filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class RandomMatrixIterator implements Iterator<int[]> {
        private Random random;

        public RandomMatrixIterator() {
            random = new Random(SEED); // Use the seed value for random number generation
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return true;  // Always have next element
        }

        @Override
        public int[] next() {
            int[] observation = new int[MATRIX_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
                observation[i] = random.nextInt(MAX_VALUE + 1);
            }
            return observation;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @talex I updated the question .. I was exaplaning the problem

Comment: `scanner.nextLine()` wait for input. You have to pres enter for it to complete.

Comment: @talex ..you are right .. the problem was at `scanner.nextline()` I updated the code .. now it creates observations, but not stopping when I press "s"

Comment: You should use `scanner.hasNextLine()` to see if there's any input and if there is, check if it's "s". But read [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Answer (score 0):

I added a listener to stop when I press "s", and added a time frame to control the time of observations creation

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RandomStreamMatrix {
    private static final int MATRIX_SIZE = 4;
    private static final int MAX_VALUE = 999;
    private static final long SEED = 1234; // Seed value for random number generation
    private static boolean generateObservations = true;
    private static int observationCount = 0;
    private static final int TIME_FRAME_MS = 10; // Time frame in milliseconds (adjust as needed)

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomStreamMatrix generator = new RandomStreamMatrix();
        Iterator<int[]> iterator = generator.new RandomMatrixIterator();

        // Create a file to write the observations
        String filePath = "observations.txt";
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath);

            // Create a JFrame to capture key events
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getKeyChar() == 's') {
                        generateObservations = false;
                        System.out.println("Generation stopped by user.");
                        System.out.println("Total observations created: " + observationCount);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
            });

            frame.setSize(200, 200);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setFocusable(true);
            frame.requestFocus();

            while (generateObservations) {
                int[] observation = iterator.next();
                System.out.println("Observation: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(observation));
                observationCount++;

                // Write the observation to the file
                for (int value : observation) {
                    fileWriter.write(Integer.toString(value) + " ");
                }
                fileWriter.write("\n");
                fileWriter.flush();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(TIME_FRAME_MS); // Pause execution for the specified time frame
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            fileWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Observations written to " + filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class RandomMatrixIterator implements Iterator<int[]> {
        private Random random;

        public RandomMatrixIterator() {
            random = new Random(SEED); // Use the seed value for random number generation
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return true; // Always have next element
        }

        @Override
        public int[] next() {
            int[] observation = new int[MATRIX_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
                observation[i] = random.nextInt(MAX_VALUE + 1);
            }
            return observation;
        }
    }
}
```